# SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://www.example.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/index?wsdl=1'

Tags: magento-1.9

SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://www.example.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/index?wsdl=1'

I have faced this kind of error when integrating the click and drop,
any solution for that.